# Battery level stuck at 6% - How do i reset?

Tags: battery, battery-life, reset

After reinstalling windows on my laptop, my laptop battery appears to be stuck at 6%. 
I dont think its very realistic, because i can still run it on battery for ages after i unplug it and no matter how much i charge it, the level wont go over 6%. 
Is there a way to reset the battery level?

Comment: Post your Make and full Model number of the Notebook for more specific answers possibly.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading a program like [BatteryCare](http://batterycare.net/en/index.html) and see if that gives you a proper reading.

EDIT: I would also try performing a full discharge. The procedure is explained in the "Guide" tab of the BatteryCare website which is linked above.